# Javascript HTTP POST input JSON error

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to add JSON request into a HTTP POST javascript code like below. Please see the code below.

My problem is, I need to input following format JSON and send it. But, I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` Could you please advise, What is wrong formatting JSON in my code below?

```
Sample JSON format to be sent=> {"records":[{"value":{"foo":"bar"}}]}
```

Code:

```
function savedata() {

    var membernameStr = parseInt(document.getElementById("MemberID").value).toString();
    var data = JSON.stringify({


        "records": [["value":{"MemberID":membernameStr,"MemberName":"Anna", "AccountNo":"7623", "Address":"Peter", "AccountType":"Peter"}]]

    });
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);

            // Based on successful response, call next POST API.
            var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr1.open("POST", "http://localhost:3500");
            xhr1.send(data);

        }
    });
    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8082/topics/topictest");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json; charset=utf-8");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.kafka.v2+json; charset=utf-8");
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

Comment: Missing quote.  `"AccountNo":"Peter,`

Comment: @Stella use like this` "records": [{"value":{"MemberID":"John","MemberName":"Anna", "AccountNo":"Peter", "Address":"Peter", "AccountType":"Peter"}}]`

Comment: Sorry, please see my updated question. Issue when I'm adding data dynamically "membernameStr"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON was incorrect in the syntax, please have a look at below JSON:

```
{
  "records": [
    [
      {
        "value": {
          "MemberID": membernameStr ,
          "MemberName": "Anna",
          "AccountNo": "7623",
          "Address": "Peter",
          "AccountType": "Peter"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> why did you use array within array ? you can also use as below ..

```
{
  "records": [
      {
        "value": {
          "MemberID": membernameStr ,
          "MemberName": "Anna",
          "AccountNo": "7623",
          "Address": "Peter",
          "AccountType": "Peter"
        }
      }
  ]
}
```